# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to build a graph from it's adjacency matrix using igraph package in python.

My `matrix(800*800)` is a text file. My code is as below, but I don't know why it keeps exiting with code `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

```
import igraph
adjacencyFile = open("AdjacencyMatrix.txt",'r')
graph = igraph.Graph.Read_Adjacency(adjacencyFile, sep=None, comment_char='#', attribute=None)
```

Comment: The point is that, when I test it with a smaller sample of the file (3*3) but with the same format, it works!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your matrix. Please upload it somewhere and paste a link here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was setting the attribute option to None, because I had some weights considerably large in the graph and it couldn't set so many edges for them.

Comment: But it was already set to "None" in the example code you provided in your question.